# pdo_oci_handle_factory: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Tags: php, oracle, laravel, laravel-5, oracle10g

I'm using Laravel 5.5, php 7.1.9, and oracle 10g

i don't know if i'm connected to the database or not and if yes, is the problem in my code ?

> PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: Error while
>   trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:640)

oracledb.php

```
return [
    'oracle' => [
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'tns'       => env('DB_TNS', 'XE'),
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'GREEN-PC'),
        'port'      => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'XE'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'esprit'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'esprit'),
        'charset'   => '',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'quoting'   => false,
    ],
];
```

in my controller

```
public function show()
{
    $res =  DB::table('esp_etudiant')
        ->where('id_et','1630242')
    ->get();
    print_r($res);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try connecting as `SYSDBA`.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
```

There are several causes for the ORA-01804 error:

- Check to make sure the following paths are set correctly in your environment:

> ```
> $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
>
> $ORACLE_HOME 
>
> $NLS_LANG
> ```

- Your oracle client may be missing some timezone dat files in the `$ORACLE_HOME` directory. You should have a separate `ORACLE_HOME` for each release of Oracle. If this is the case, then :

> The first thing to do is to check if ORA_TZFILE is set and if it is,
>   remove it and restart the database and listener. Oracle will then try
>   to load the $ORACLE_HOME/oracore/zoneinfo/timezlrg.dat file.
>
> If for some reason the file that Oracle wants to use is not available
>   then this is the cause of the problem.
>
> If the file is present then an alternative reason for the error could
>   be that Oracle cannot load the file because of permission problems.
>
> If all above is correct then it might be a .dat file that is corrupt.

- Check that the permissions are set to allow reads (`chmod 444`) for the files in the `OCCI library`.

Comment: I checked the paths and the permissions, but how to fix the timezone problem?

Comment: @FirasHakimi ok, i've edited for `timezone problem` just now.

Comment: you have any idea how to fix this
PDOException
SQLSTATE[]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: OCI_INVALID_HANDLE (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:640)

Comment: @FirasHakimi unfortunately, it seems it's related with php, and i don't know much about php.