# cx_Oracle.DatabeseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Tags: cx-oracle

When I'm executing queries in Pydev-Eclipse environment with cx_Oracle it's throwing the error

cx_Oracle.DatabeseError: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804

Please someone help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdo\_oci\_handle\_factory: Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47491084/pdo-oci-handle-factory-error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01804)

Comment: I didn't get that. Could you explain briefly?

Comment: If cx_Oracle is linked with Oracle libraries in a full Oracle DB install, then make sure the ORACLE_HOME environment variable is set for the Python executable.